# Gatling - Retrieve part of json and check equality

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I'm using Gatling tool to load test my service.
I have following response from my server(just an example):

```
{
  "result: {
    "288249": {
      "allowEdit": 1,
      "cells": [
        {
          "rollupId": "288249",
          "description": "Gatling description: 93"
        },
        {
          "rollupId": "288249",
          "description": "Gatling description: 83"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I need is loop thought all $.result.288249.cells[*].description fields and verify that there's a value, which is equal to what I have in one of my session objects. 
It should look similar to following pseudo code:

```
.check(
    jsonPath("$.result.*.cells[*].description").contains("${mySessionValue})
)
```

Is there are method, which I can use in similar way ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I think, I've found the solution

```
    .check(
      jsonPath("$.result.*.cells[?(@.description == '${mySessionValue}')]")
        .find
        .exists
    )
```

This should do the work.

Comment: You don't even need `find` and `exists` as those are the default values for those check steps.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, you've created very powerful instrument ;)

Comment: Thanks for your kind words :)

Answer (score -1):

You can loop thru as follows

```
$.each($.result, function(index,obj){
        $.each(obj['cells'], function(innerInd, innerObj){
            if( ${mySessionValue} == innerObj['description'] )
            {
                console.log('Found')
                return 
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: You answer is not what I was expecting to see. I need an Gatling expert, which can show how it should be done